# How to move a directory which is not empty using PHP?

Tags: php

I need your help with my problem because I am creating a PHP program that can move directories. How can I move a directory? Here's my sample code.

```
    $base = "C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/";
    $folders_count = (count(glob("$base/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR))); 

    $ones = "000";
    $tens = "00";
    $hundreds = "0";

    for($x = 1; $x <= $folders_count; $x++){

        if($x < 10){

            if(file_exists($base.$ones.$x)){

                if(file_exists($base.$ones.$x."/img")){

                                 //Here's what I did
                                 rename("C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/0001/img/M", "C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/0001/");
                                 //It is static only for testing but there's an error
                     //Here's my problem here because the folder img has two folders. They are folder 'M' and folder 'R' and each folder has a photo inside.

                } 

            }

        }


    }
```

My base folder directory is: **C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/**

And inside /003006 have 44 folders that's why I loop them. Inside the loop is my process.

The directory that I need to move inside /003006 are:

```
/003006/img/M/0001/A.jpg
/003006/img/R/0001/A.jpg
```

What I need is to get out the folders /M and /R inside /img. Now it should be like this:

```
/003006
  - /M/0001/A.jpg
  - /R/0001/A.jpg
```

By the way the folders inside /M and /R are up to 0001-0050. And inside these folders contain 6 images.

Here's the error I got using rename command.

```
Warning: rename(C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/0001/img/M,C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/trash/francis-hht-addtional/C/003006/0001/) [function.rename]: ƒAƒNƒZƒX‚ª‹‘”Û‚³‚ê‚Ü‚µ‚½B (code: 5) in C:\wamp\www\Chelle\move_image.php on line 62
```

Comment: `rename($old, $new)` should work: http://php.net/rename

Comment: Ok sorry, I have that code but there's an error. Check my code above I already updated it.

Comment: Or perhaps try using curl. Works well with php

Comment: @les - thanks but I don't have an idea of what you're suggesting. Can you provide me an example of it?

Comment: I'll definitely try and scrap one up tonight if you still need it then.